# puppet upgrade kubernetes now kubelet won't stay up

Tags: kubernetes

Made a mistake in a puppet config and inadvertently let puppet upgrade a kubernetes cluster to 1.13.0. Since k8 wants a somewhat involved upgrade process the whole thing was fairly botched.

After running the process manually and getting all impacted nodes and master to the same version it seems that **kubelet** (and thus the api server) will run for 20-30 minutes and then stop responding.

As it starts to get unhappy the log begins seeing more entries like these:

> level=error msg="Error running exec in container: rpc error: code = 2 desc = oci runtime error: exec failed: container_linux.go:247: starting container process caused \"process_linux.go:110: decoding init error from pipe caused \\"read parent: connection reset by peer\\"\"\n"

and

> file.go:182] Not recursing into manifest path "/etc/kubernetes/manifests/<path>"

with various namespace entries for **path**. This cycle repeats every 20 seconds until kubelet eventually stops responding. If I manually restart kubelet it works for a while and begins the cycle anew.

Did I miss something in the upgrade process?

---

### Edit:

```
[root@kube-master ~]# rpm -qa | grep docker
docker-client-1.13.1-84.git07f3374.el7.centos.x86_64
docker-1.13.1-84.git07f3374.el7.centos.x86_64
docker-common-1.13.1-84.git07f3374.el7.centos.x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first error message looks very likely [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53605666/cant-execute-bash-in-docker-container).

Maybe you can check if those affetcted nodes are running a recent version docker?

Comment: I added the docker version info to the original question

Comment: Interesting. That seems to have made a big difference in the error rate if nothing else.